# Search all pixels and PNGs in a single grab using ImageGrab in Python

Tags: python

I am having some problems with multi-process in Xlib.thread or ImageGrab.
When I put like 3 or more references to get (getPixel and locateOnScreen(pyautogui)) in multi threads, it works fast and without errors initially, but 2 or 3 hours later the commands are getting slow and an error appears in the cmd warning that "it can't happen!"

Here's an example of the code:

```
    from PIL import ImageGrab, Image
    from pymouse import PyMouse
    from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard
    import time
    m = PyMouse()
    k = PyKeyboard()
    def start(self):
        if self.hotkeyEscolhidaManaTraining != None:
                self.isManaTrainingOn = True
        if self.isManaTrainingOn:
            self.timerstartManaTraining=Interval.set_interval(self.startManaTraining, 1)
    def startManaTraining(self):
        if self.runningTimerManaTraining == True:
            self.timerstartManaTraining.cancel()
            return
        self.runningTimerManaTraining = True
        ManaTrainingBox = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Pics/heal/manaLow.png', 0.8, True)
        startBoxLeft = ManaTrainingBox[0]+2
        self.startBoxTopManaTraining = ManaTrainingBox[1]+5
        pixeisTotais = 92
        if self.isManaTrainingOn:
            pixelManaTraining = (self.porcentagemEscolhidaManaTraining * pixeisTotais) / 100
            self.endBoxLeftManaTraining = startBoxLeft + pixelManaTraining
            self.timerManaTraining = Interval.set_interval(self.validateManaTraining, 0.5)
    def validateManaTraining(self): 
        if self.isManaTrainingOn:
            pixelRGB = ImageGrab.getPixel((self.endBoxLeftManaTraining, self.startBoxTopManaTraining))
        if not self.validatePixelsMana(pixelRGB):
            pyautogui.press(self.hotkeyEscolhidaManaTraining)
            return
```

and others 10 code like this in multi-threads, have a way to get all pixels and PNGs in just one 'locateOnScreen' without saving the img?

Comment: i think you can do it better using  python opencv  and pyautogui . Can you describe what you want obtain from image grabbed from the screen ?  Some example images can be appreciated

Comment: is one of scripts (functions) to a bot or macro in game, to do repeated things in game, according the variables of the game, the game is a 2d game called "Tibia"

Comment: I assume you don't have the source code of the game. Right ?

Comment: The Tibia is a game in application in my case Linux this is a pic = https://i.imgur.com/DoSO1vf.png
I already do somethings and works fine, but according the time, the 'bot' is getting slower and more slower until he crash
https://i.imgur.com/IU6Jsqr.png

Comment: On a 1920 x 1080 screen, the locate function calls take about 1 or 2 seconds. This may be too slow for action video games, but works for most purposes and applications.   Maybe you can do screen image resizing and then use "locateOnScreen", so it should be faster.